# Como localizar determinado campo na tela do meu computador e extrair suas informações?

Tags: python, web-scraping

saudações,

Estou buscando como eu conseguiria extrair informações de um software que utilizo.
Eu precisaria realizar uma validação em tempo real para validar informações do CPF do cadastro aberto no momento.

Em pesquisa, só encontrei formas de fazer isso com webscrapping e extração por imagem, porém eu precisaria realizar essa extração durante a utilização do software.

Existe alguma solução possível?

Answer (score -2):

Boa tarde, como sua proposta é utilizá-lo localmente, eu sugeriria usar o PyAutoGui, que "automatiza" o seu computador, permitindo, assim que você use seu aparelho, que em seguida iniciaria seu software, buscaria a informação que você deseja, e em seguida enviaria ou guardaria em algum local de sua preferência, local ou mesmo na nuvem, sendo que o próprio PyAutoGui consegue, com os comandos certos, navegar na internet.